# pyodbc works when exectued as a script, doesn't work when compiled to exe

Tags: python, sql-server, pyinstaller, pyodbc

I have a strange problem with pyodbc in particular.
So when I run my application natively it works flawlessly it does everything it is supposed to.
Mainly gathering and changing some information from SAP, storing it in a CSV and then importing the given CSV into mssql.

All would be great if when I compile it to an exe with pyinstaller (tried both one file and regular), everything runs great the application starts without any errors, only the SQL server connection cannot be established (tried multiple SQL drivers, no luck). I am using the same PC for everything. I have compiled to exe some smaller apps with no problems whatsoever. I've also try adding hidden imports also to no avail.

Does anybody have a clue what is the cause of this issue?

Comment: So you get no errors at all on the console when launching the .exe file from a Command Prompt window?

Comment: No errors whatsoever, in the meantime I found a workaround, but I am not sure what in fact is different than my previous method. I have created a function which is called by pressing a button. But the function is the same as the code I used to connect to the SQL server that was in my script at the start. Basically button press to connect works, connect automatically upon execution not working. I guess the problem could be in the order the functions are executed when the program is ran, didn't have the time to try it.